# How to detect when the socket is opened on client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

While using `socket.io` on the client browser side, how can I detect when the socket actually opened? Along with all the other basic default messages (such as errors and disconnection)

I am referring to how the default WebSocket API has `websocket.onopen = function(){}`, `.onerror` and `.onclose`.

Using `socket.on("connect", function(){some code here})` and `socket.on("connection")` does nothing.

Comment: there is an example showing how to do that on http://socket.io/ did you try it ?

Comment: @user3 yes, none of the examples cover how to do this on the client/browser side.

Comment: there are documents that describe a event called 'connection_error' and 'disconnect' hasn't to be explained.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at:
[Docs of SocketIO](http://socket.io/docs/)

because it is such an easy question im adding the message below.

it isnt hard to find the solution to this, just search and you will find what you need.
It is wrong to (be lazy) and ask your question on a platform such as stackoverflow for **all** you programming information. it is always better to look for docs and examples. because you learn more when you look it up yourself or find it out yourself.

of course you can ask questions when you are really stuck and you cant move forward and you know for sure it takes to long otherwise.

*if you want the easy way here is the solution:*

http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-receiving-events
http://socket.io/docs/client-api/

use "disconnect", when disconnect event is triggered on times you dont expect, its is clearly a connection drop.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

Comment: http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager(url:string,-opts:object) does nothing on the clientside, socket.on("connect", function_here)  triggers nothing. I did research, I am stuck and I have already tried code which doesn't work, which is why I am here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so before I tried this

```
socket.on("connect", function(){
    alert("socket open test")
})
```

and it didn't work but and now I tried again and somehow for some reason it does, sorry for the confusion and waste of time.